# Make form-style information display on a webpage

Tags: css, forms, input, inject

I have a website (bootleg/css) I put together. I am currently implementing user registration but I am having troubles determining the best way to go about the following:

I have users that will be entering their teammates,  and themselves into a tournament (via a form). That's the easy part. Once the users have input their info, I'd like the webpage to populate with the registered team in a designated area. The structure as so:

(Registration form)

**TEAM NAME**

**Member 1**

**Member 2**

**Member 3**

**Member 4**

I want it to take TEAM NAME and display it in a specific section of a webpage for those registered. Like so:

(Displayed as so)

**REGISTERED TEAMS:**

**Slayers**

**Dominatrix**

**Evolution**

I am most familiar with css and html, but I am willing to work with php as long as it can be injected into the current site. I have a MySQL server setup and can edit it further. I've done a LOT on the design side, but not too much on the scripting side until recently so go easy on me.

Comment: Looks like it messed with the format a bit.  The teams and form would be stacked VERTICALLY.

Comment: You will want to show some of the code that you have already.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. I am trying to finisb up my table when I get home this evening so I can get a little help, and give you a little more to work with.Salim, that answer is helpful. Though,  with this I dont understand how it wouldn't confuse one teamname submitted from another.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply using PHP and MySQL.As you said,you are familiar with MySQL,I would give you the outline to do this.

Make a table for the registered users,Insert data to MySQL Database using INSERT Query in MySQL.

```
 INSERT INTO Table_name (id,member_name,member_age,...) VALUE ('','$name','$age',...)
```

You can select all the values using SELECT Query from Database Table,and echo it on HTML part,where you want to show the result.

```
 SELECT * FROM Table_name
```